# F-string in Python ":.3f"

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

I'm reading this textbook called "Practical Statistics for Data Scientists" and this `:.3f` keeps getting used in almost every `f-string`. What does `:.3f` mean? My guess is it has something to do with floating point numbers.

Example:

```
 {house_lm_factor.intercept_:.3f}
```

Comment: *"format this value as a **f**loat to **3** decimal places"*

Comment: Please se [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is show you how many number are printing:

```
>>> import math
>>> flt = math.pi
>>> f'{flt:.3f}'
'3.142'

>>> f'{flt:.5f}'
'3.14159'

>>> f'{flt:.10f}'
'3.1415926536'
```